# is there any term given to people who like smoking?

Tags: vocabulary, proper-nouns

Is it called smoker?

I just have done a google search with this:

**term to people who like smoking**

Comment: How about 'chain smoker'?

Comment: It would be "term *for* people who like to smoke". You might find some advertising terms for cigarette-lover here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vintage+cigarette+ads&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifr8PQ4JLWAhVG7CYKHYHwCWgQ_AUICigB&biw=1785&bih=794

Comment: Unfortunately smoking is a drug habit. I suspect there are many people who smoke but don't like it (why so many people try to quit). So *smoker* by itself isn't helpful. I would just use *like* if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways of referring to people who like smoking could be:

> Smoking Enthusiast
>
> Cigarette Enthusiast

The word 'enthusiast' means (according to Merriam-Webster [Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enthusiast)):

> One who tends to become ardently absorbed in an interest

You can also say 'x' followed by "Enthusiast", being 'x' the specific thing that is being smoked, like Cigar (the big ones) Enthusiast, Marihuana Enthusiast, etc.

Also, regarding your first question, *smoker* refers to one that smokes, regardless they enjoy it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Smoker is the one who smokes. However, you want something that describes that they *like* smoking! Well, I'm not sure whether such term exist. But this may work:

> A cigarette lover 
>  A cigar lover